# Cloud Control Error cctrluser key.add

Tags: cloudcontrol

I installed cctrl and tried to create a public key, I typed cctrluser key.add at Command Prompt, I received error. Could someone please help?

```
C:\Users\sumit>cctrluser key.add
Key 'C:\Users\sumit/.ssh/id_rsa.pub' seems to be invalid or not found!
Type "Yes" to generate a new default SSH-key pair: yes
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "cctrluser", line 150, in <module>
File "cctrluser", line 34, in main
File "cctrluser", line 144, in parse_cmdline
File "cctrl\common.pyo", line 99, in run
File "cctrl\user.pyo", line 124, in addKey
File "cctrl\keyhelpers.pyo", line 149, in create_new_default_ssh_keys
File "cctrl\keyhelpers.pyo", line 57, in generate_rsa_keys
File "cctrl\keyhelpers.pyo", line 85, in generate_rsa_key_manually
File "cctrl\keyhelpers.pyo", line 101, in generate_private_rsa_key_file
File "paramiko\__init__.pyo", line 65, in <module>
File "paramiko\transport.pyo", line 45, in <module>
File "paramiko\ecdsakey.pyo", line 24, in <module>
ImportError: No module named ecdsa
```

Comment: Same problem here. If you find something please let me know .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found a solution .

Get Git Bash.

Then use the following command :

> $ ssh-keygen -C youremail@provider.com

Save the ssh created into id_rsa ( default, suggested place )

youremail@provider.com is the email you used to create the cloudcontrol account .

Then go into your cloudcontrol account and add the content of the ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub in the SSH keys input .

Comment: thanks man, that helped
i will upvote you as soon as i get 15 reputation))

Comment: -C (the comment in the key) can actually be whatever you want. The default is the current user and hostname which is sufficient in most cases

Answer (score 1):

New [cctrl](https://www.cloudcontrol.com/download/win) version has been released today with fixed ecdsa dependency, so automatic ssh key generation is supported again.